# Will I visit all the explorable zones if I follow the personal storyline to the end?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The next mission is going to take place in a new zone, and I'm split between completing a nearby zone now, where no mission has taken place so far and I just happened to wander in, or coming back later if the personal storyline is going to take me there eventually.

My race is Sylvari, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I havn't completed the story yet, but I doubt the story takes you to all zones. since the story quests go up in level each time, the chances of them going back to low level zones is small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will not receive missions for each zone with your personal storyline. Which zones you travel through will depend on your race and the decisions made during character creation and during your storyline.

I recently completed the personal storyline, and found roughly half a dozen zones that I had never been to.

Comment: Do bear in mind that some POI's can only be reached through the story missions. Such as the 'Trahearne Speech' area in Fort Trinity.

Comment: @DavidYell That is no longer true, btw.